# Are tikz and pgf designed to be pdf/a compliant? Good for Production Quality Scientific Data Graphing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf-a

Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76011224/is-there-an-r-4-2-1-pdf-a-compliant-pdf-output-device .

Apparently, `R` can output to a `Ti*k*Z` device (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html). `Ti*k*Z` in turn works through pgf to generate PDF. `R` does not seem to have a good device that can generate PDF/A compatible output (`CairoPDF` is only PDF compatible), so maybe the `Ti*k*Z` device is a good route?! (One concern going this long route is that there are many moving wheels involved, all of which can break.)

Are pgf and `Ti*k*Z` designed to be guaranteed PDF/A compliant? And/or can resulting figures be easily guaranteed to become PDF/A compliant? (e.g., including package pdfx.)

Has anyone compared resulting file sizes (e.g., a `CairoPDF` scatterplot graph and equivalent pdflatex-tikz-pgf-pdf scatterplot standalone graph)? Are there other reasons why pdflatex-tikz-pgf-pdf would be a bad idea for production-quality scientific graphing of data?

Comment: well pdf/A doesn't like it if two color models are used, so should force either cmyk or rgb depending on what the document in which you include the graphic uses. And pdf/A-1 doesn't like transparency, so either avoid it, or use pdf/A-2 (see https://pdfa.org/making-pdf-a-conversion-easier/). xmp-metadata can be added in various way but this is unrelated to tikz.

Comment: ok, but in principle, pgf can be made easily compliant.  see, CairoPDF() in R opens the device with transparency enabled, making it thereafter difficult to fix.  they also omit a few proper closings...somewhat sloppily.  usually no harm, except when it comes to pdf/a.  for completeness, how do I force either cmyk or rgb into latex document output?

Comment: well "easily" is perhaps a bit too optimistic, there are a few things like patterns and shadings where getting the color model right isn't completly trivial. You can force a color model with xcolor either with a package option or with \selectcolormodel. you need a suitable colorprofile (I have no idea how to tell pdfx to use a cmyk profile, by default it will use rgb.)